# How to plot store points on a map (react native)

Tags: react-native

I have been working on an app and I am using MapView from react-native-maps. I wanted to know how I could put points on the map based on the store's address? I do not have too much of a clue of how to convert an address into a log and lat. I would assume that the store owner would type in their address and that address would convert to long and lat? I do know that it would entail MapView.Marker. If someone can provide me with a youtube video, give me some advice or a link where I can read up on the logic of this! I plan to have multiple stores. I do know that this would probably include a database however, I am trying to achieve a working BETA version.

[Here is an idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TB3wL.png)! When you open the app you are greeted with multiple bird scooters where the user can walk to. I wanted to provide the same effect rather when you open the app all the stores within a certain radius are there for your viewing pleasure.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To convert an address to lat/long coordinates you need to use a geocoding service. Here is an example if you use Google Maps: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple